# How to put image retrieved from url into an image widget

Tags: python, image, widget, ipywidgets

I found this code and it works fine. The image can be retrieved and displayed.

```
import IPython
url = 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/colorful-background-14.jpg'
IPython.display.Image(url, width = 250)
```

However, I actually want to put the image into an image widget, so I have tried this:

```
import IPython
from ipywidgets import widgets

url = 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/colorful-background-14.jpg'
image = IPython.display.Image(url, width = 300)

widgets.Image(
  value=image,
  format='jpg', 
  width=300,
  height=400,
)
```

But I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TraitError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-5011b6084128> in <module>()
     57     format='jpg',
     58     width=300,
---> 59     height=400,
     60 )

________________________________________
7 frames
________________________________________
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py in error(self, obj, value)
    623             e = "The '%s' trait must be %s, but a value of %r was specified." \
    624                 % (self.name, self.info(), repr_type(value))
--> 625         raise TraitError(e)
    626 
    627     def get_metadata(self, key, default=None):

TraitError: The 'value' trait of an Image instance must be a bytes object, but a value of 
<IPython.core.display.Image object> <class 'IPython.core.display.Image'> was specified.
```

So, my question is: how can I put the image into an image widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly thanks for your minimal example.

The error tells you what you need to do. You need to pass the `bytes` of the image file to the `ipywidgets.Image` class. Do this by passing `image.data` from your `Ipython.display.Image` instance.

```py
import IPython
from ipywidgets import widgets

url = 'https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/colorful-background-14.jpg'
image = IPython.display.Image(url, width = 300)

widgets.Image(
  value=image.data,
  format='jpg', 
  width=300,
  height=400,
)
```

Alternatively, use a package like `requests` to get the `bytes` of the image and pass them to `widgets.Image`, without the need for the `Ipython.display.Image` instance.